# How to use a getter in another class?

Tags: flutter, class, title, getter

In my class `Tabelle` I handed over a title. Now i want to output a `Text(this.title)` in the class `_TabelleState`. But i get the error 'the getter title isnt defined for the type _TabelleState'

How can I use this.title in the _TabelleState class?

```
class Tabelle extends StatefulWidget {
  Tabelle({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  
  @override
  _TabelleState createState() => _TabelleState();
}

class _TabelleState extends State<Tabelle> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(this.title),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Stateful widgets you can access the associated widget from its state:

```dart
class Tabelle extends StatefulWidget {
  Tabelle({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  
  @override
  _TabelleState createState() => _TabelleState();
}

class _TabelleState extends State<Tabelle> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),// Here is the magic
```